# error: ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is my code for the Adaptive Monte Carlo localization(AMCL) algorithm, a plugin using for ign gazebo(citadel) and ROS(melodic).

void amcl::Configure(const Entity &_entity,
const std::shared_ptr &_sdf,
EntityComponentManager &_ecm,
EventManager &_eventMgr)

{
this->dataPtr->model = Model(_entity);
if (!this->dataPtr->model.Valid(_ecm))
{

```
ignerr << "amcl plugin should be attached to a model entity. "
       << "Failed to initialize." << std::endl;
return;
}

// Obtain parameters from xacro file

if(_sdf->HasElement("topicRate"))
{
    rate_ = _sdf->GetElement("topicRate")->Get<double>(); #############ERROR IN THIS LINE 

}
else
{
  rate_ = 10.0;
}


if(_sdf->HasElement("fixedFrame"))

{
    fixed_frame_ = _sdf->GetElement("fixedFrame")->Get<std::string>(); ########ERROR IN THIS LINE 
    
}
else
{
    fixed_frame_ = "map";
}

if(_sdf->HasElement("robotFrame"))
    
{
    robot_frame_ = _sdf->GetElement("robotFrame")->Get<std::string>(); #####ERROR IN THIS LINE
    
}
else
{
    robot_frame_ = "base_link";
}
```

Error (as shown in the terminal)

> error: passing
> ‘std::__shared_ptr_access<const
> sdf::v9::Element,
> (__gnu_cxx::Lock_policy)2, false,
> false>::element_type’ {aka ‘const
> sdf::v9::Element’} as ‘this’ argument
> discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> rate =
> _sdf->GetElement("topicRate")->Get();

I have marked the lines in the code which throw this error.

Complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/addy1997/ignition-gazebo-plugins/blob/main/Amcl.cc) with the [header](https://github.com/addy1997/ignition-gazebo-plugins/blob/main/Amcl.hh) file (Amcl.hh)

Can anybody suggest a solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26792/error:-%E2%80%98this%E2%80%99-argument-discards-qualifiers-%5B-fpermissive%5D/) by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am answering my own question
To understand the proposed changes, one should have some familiarity with concepts related to ignition gazebo

change Line 95, 107, 118 with the following lines

```
auto rate_ = _sdf->Get<double>("topicRate"); //line 95

auto fixed_frame_ = _sdf->Get<std::string>("fixedFrame"); //107

auto robot_frame_ = _sdf->Get<std::string>("robotFrame"); //118
```

---

Originally posted by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) with karma: 7 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0